# How to filter the content of a field in a Dreamweaver Template Building block

Tags: html, dreamweaver, tridion

I am working on Dreamweaver TBB in SDL Tridion 2011.

Say my component has a  field "aaa" with this content.

```
"hi hello <bbb name='abcd_efgh_ijkl'>MRJJJJ</bbb> how are you"
```

I want to write a DWT TBB such that i will produce the output as

```
"hi hello MRJJJJ how are you".
```

So I want to strip out some part of the Content in a field (here field name is aaa) when I render for display purposes.

I am new to this and got stuck here.

Comment: Can you clarify your question - Are you really trying to edit the content of a Component? Or do you mean that you want to strip out some of the content/tags when you render it for display purposes?

Comment: @ChrisSummers i have edited in the question reg this.

Comment: It's always good to consider how you would do it without Tridion first. Once you have the answer you apply that to Tridion. Tridion development is not some magic art, it is generally .Net development,  Java development, JavaScript development or XML development depending where in the system you're working. If you try to find the answer with Tridion from the start you will often miss the most obvious and easy-to-implement solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the value of that field and place it in your template package using either a C# Fragment or a Microsoft.NET Assembly TBB. You can then manipulate the value using C#, and output the modified value using DWT by using @@NameOfModifiedValueInPackage@@. The other suggestions of Function Sources or a different type of Mediator are equally valid. However, most projects require some sort of .NET TBB anyway, so this should not be much additional work.

Comment: ..Thank you for the suggestion.AS suggested by you I thought of implementing this way.

Comment: ..Thank you for the suggestion.As suggested by you I thought of implementing this way.
1.Create DWT TBB
2.Apply .Net TBB on it to modify content as per the requirement without modifying actual content in Component(just to modify the view).
3.Need to apply site Edit
4.default Finish actions.

Here I have two doubts.
1.If we do some manipulations on the output of DWT TBB will it effect in main component.I don't want that to affect in my component.
2.How do i supply output of DWT TBB for the .net TBB.
Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Manipulating the output of the DWT template will only change the rendered content of the item in the package, your Component will not be touched as templates are read only (unless you have intentionally change the default behavior of the CMS in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1).

I also think you will find it easier to retrieve and manipulate the content if you do it before the DWT transformation is applied, as the HTML from the DWT has a less structured format.  

If you must do it 'Post DWT', you just load the item called 'Output' from the package using a .NET assembly.

Answer (score 4):

In a DWT TBB in Tridion you should typically only retrieve values from the Component. Processing those values is not something you'd do in the DWT.

If you do need such processing, have a look at implementing a custom IFunctionSource. With that you could write something like this in your DWT:

```
@@StripXhtml("aaa")@@
```

So you'd implement your own StripXhtml function in an IFunctionSource class.

For a great example of such a function source, have a look at Nuno's [Dreamweaver Get Extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx) over on SDL Tridion World.

If you are really intent on combining HTML and processing into a single TBB, you may want to consider using a template language that supports the combination better. The [XSLT Mediator](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/xsltmediator.aspx) and the [Razor Mediator](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/razormediator.aspx) are good examples of such template types.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a ResolveXHTML kind of issue.

Are you using the 'Default Finish Actions' TBB as the last TBB in your compound template?  This contains a ResolveXHTML function that converts Tridion RTF field content and removes namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you really understand what you're trying to do.

Looking at the sample you're using here, it looks like you're trying to replace some text with a dynamic variable - like a user name. However, if you do this in a Dreamweaver Template it will be executed at publish time, not at the time the page is served to a visitor on your website, resulting in the same value being displayed to EVERY visitor of the site.